# Еще о предлогах "в" и "на"

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, топонимика

В связи с предыдущим вопросом хочу спросить. Если предлог *на* употребляется тогда, когда речь идет об островах, тогда почему говорят "на Камчатку" или "на Таймыр", хоть это полуострова? А, если *на* относится и к полуостровам, то почему тогда - "в Крым"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хороший вопрос. На самом деле далеко не со всеми названиями полуостровов употребляются предлог на. "Во Флориду", например.
Для выбора предлога в момент появления топонима решающим фактором было то, насколько существенным для говорящих было то, что объект - полуостров, и то насколько вообще географическое понятие совпадает с границами полуострова. Для Крыма оба фактора были не в пользу предлога "НА". Сам полуостров воспринимался как естественное продолжение причерноморских степей, а понятие "Крым" изначально означало Крымское ханство, границы влияния которого распространялись далеко за пределы полуострова. Так что предлог "В" данном случае вполне оправдан с исторической точки зрения.
Интересно, что даже в отношении названия "Таврида" ("Таврия"), которым обозначался собственно полуостров, тоже не было единообразия. Употреблялось и "в Тавриду", и "на Тавриду".

Comment: Мне, кажется, что, говоря "во Флориду", все-таки имеют в виду штат, а не полуостров.

Comment: С чего бы? Америкпнцам, допустим, это важно, а русским-то, которых интересуют пляжи, крокодилы или космодром?  
Впрочем, это только подтверждало бы мою мысль.

Answer (score 1):

Почему говорят "на Украине", а не "в Украине"? Почему говорят "в Крыму", а не "на Крыму"? Мне кажется всё относительно просто. Украина во времена Запорожской Сечи, в принципе, не имела чётких границ, а полуостров Крым имел. Потому и "поехал в Крым", что за границы полуострова если и попадёшь, то окажешься не в Крыму, а в море. А сотню-другую километров ошибся в Дикой Степи (так называлась эта территория в 16-м веке) , всё-равно ты на территории Украины будешь.
Кроме того, употребляя "иду на Москву", подразумевалось, что грабить будут не только Москву, но и все окрестности, а также всё и всех по пути следования "на Москву". И в то же время, употребляя "еду в Москву", подразумевалось пребывание (нахождение) внутри границ Москвы.
Употребляя "иду на Вы", подразумевается не только переход на официальное обращение к лицу, но и соответствующие изменения отношений в целом без конкретных перечислений пунктов изменений.

Answer (score 0):

С названиями полуостровов употребляется тот же предлог, что и с названиями островов (предлог *на*). 'В Крым/ в Крыму' - это исключение.

Answer (score 0):

Есть такое правило употребления предлогов "в" и " на" при движении:

в ----> из

на----> с (со)

Поясню. если: 1) возвращаемся **из** (города), то движемся **в** (город);
              2) бежим **с** (площадки), то идем **на** (площадку).

Например: из Крыма - в Крым;  с Камчатки - на Камчатку; со стадиона - на стадион.

Comment: Ну, это скорее мнемоническая подсказка, чем объяснение. Почему же не 2Из Камчатки"? 

Кстати, я бы сказала "на Украину" и "из Украины". Впрочем, теперь, кажется, политкорректным будет "в Украину"  ;-))

Comment: Нет, это далеко не только мнемоника. Это семнтика. В и ИЗ в этом значении антонимичны, аналогично НА и С.

"В" здесь означает "вовнуть"; обратное действие - "ИЗ" (изнутри).
"НА" - на верх (чего-либо), на повехность; обратно - С.
-----
Народ российский бестолков,
Украйна - то ж страна! 
Готов идти я только "В",
А посылают НА!  
©2003

Comment: Конечно, это так, но наличие "из" нисколько не понятнее, чем "в". Если я понимаю характер движения, я и так выберу правильный предлог. Но он не всегда понятен. Есть ситуации, где эта разница стирается.  
Почему "В Москву", но "на Таймыр"? И то и другое - некая географическая площадь и, также, административное образование. Т.е. Таймыр больше похож на "площадку", а Москва - на некую полость, _в_ которую можно попасть? Это все условно!

Answer (score 0):

Для меня подобные вопросы уже не существенны, поскольку начал задумываться над словами, как отражением мыслеобраза. Приведу пример развития мысли: Чем отличается вода в стакане от воды на стакане? Или чем отличается пластырь на заднице от пластыря в заднице?
Все очень просто: Если Вы имеете ввиду горы, реки или острова, то правильно говорить На!!!
Поскольку Вы не похожи на крота, который живет внутри острова. Если Вы говорите о стране, то уместнее применять предлог В!!! Поскольку Вы имеете ввиду события внутри страны, а не над ней. Равно как и человек может находиться на дороге или на реке (если конечно он не закатан в асфальт или не утопленник) Также человек может находиться на горе и в горе и соответственно быть или альпинистом или шахтером. За время развития язык славян очень исказили и многие понятия настолько искажены, что их не возможно понять!!!
Приведу пример как отучаю себя от мата: Известное выражение: Иди Ты в задницу!!!
Идти-шагать наступать! Поскольку Вы предлагаете идти оппоненту, то подразумевается Ваша задница! Соответственно выражение: Наступи мне на задницу или пни по ней!!!
То же касается и детородных органов.
Язык образов был силен во времена, когда буквы и слова обозначали определенный мыслеобраз и это отражено в славянской азбуке, которую перевернули с ног на голову:
http://перепросмотр.рф/slavyanskaya-azuka.html
http://www.krupenichka.ru/slavalf.html
http://www.knlife.ru/slavyanskaya-azbuka.html
http://www.slavianin.ru/nasledie/stati/slavyanskaya-azbuka.-znachenie-bukvits.html
В славянской азбуке перечислен путь человека от Аз (я) индивидуального к Я коллективному: Я-народ, Я-земля, Я-вселенная!!!
Еще при Иване Грозном и Пушкине славянская азбука имела вес в обществе и именно поэтому поэтам удавалось удивительно точно передавать образы и настроение себя и природы.
Как говорилось тогда: Азм есьм царь!
Как говорится сейчас: Я есть царь!!!
С уважением, Алексей!