# Как правильно: "вернуться НА начало" или "вернуться В начало"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, существительные

Имеется в виду навигация по сайту.
Когда пользователь проходит все интерактивные этапы, то в конце ему предлагается *вернуться **на / в** начало.*

*Как правильно: **на** или **в**? И почему?*

Это интерактивный опрос, который состоит из пяти шагов. И имеется в виду начало этого опроса.

Comment: Вопрос о предлогах В и НА неоднократно обсуждался на этом сайте. Вот некоторые ссылки: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/49590/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0;  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/%d0%95%d1%89%d0%b5-%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%b2-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0;

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/42437/%d0%92%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%92-%d0%b8-%d0%9d%d0%90; 
https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/16713/%d0%9d%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%85%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%85%d0%bd%d0%b5/16719#16719; 
https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/3082/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%b2

Comment: @М_Г, это очень хорошо, что обсуждался. И я так понимаю, что Вы на основе этих вопросов можете дать мне ответ на мой.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, что правильно будет так:
*вернуться **в начало сайта**; но: вернуться **на первую страницу сайта**.*

Глагол **"вернуться"** может иметь два предлога: вернуться **на** Родину, вернуться **в** строй. Предлог **В** обычно используется, когда предмет имеет сложное внутреннее строение.

К примеру, книга, состоящая из многих страниц, имеет начало и конец.
Поэтому мы говорим: начало книги,  в начале книги, вернуться в начало книги. Но можно вернуться на какую-нибудь страницу, если рассматривать ее отдельно от книги.

Answer (score 2):

Хотелось бы понять, в начало чего мы возвращаемся. Как отметил @Niemand, некорректно говорить о "начале сайта". Но возможно, говорится о начале игры, начале списка  или чего-то подобного. Лучше всего подобрать что-то более конкретное, подходящее к данному случаю, например "на первую страницу", "на начальный этап" и т.п.

Если рассматривать вопрос абстрактно, без привязки к контексту, то подходит "вернуться в начало" или "вернуться к началу", а также "перейти в начало" и "перейти к началу".

Для справки: вопрос о предлогах В и НА неоднократно обсуждался на этом сайте (см. ссылки в моем комментарии к вопросу).

Answer (score 1):

Что такое "начало сайта"? Некорректное же сочетание! Поэтому и обе фразы некорректны. Напишите "на главную страницу", и дело с концом.

Comment: Это опрос, который состоит из пяти шагов. И имеется в виду начало этого опроса.

Comment: Возможные варианты: вернитесь к первому шагу, вернитесь к началу опроса (в начало опроса)